# Call button click using JavaScript or jQuery is not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-events

```
document.getElementById("button").click();
```

or

```
$("#button").click();
```

is not working in Firefox

Please help me

Comment: have you included jquery file ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("button").click();` not working => OK because, `click()` is a jQuery method and your element is not wrapped in jQuery. `$("#button").click();` must work. Can you show your HTML pls ?